# When running RStan jobs in R on a cluster, is it possible using too many cores will result in insufficient memory?

Tags: r, cluster-computing, rstan

I am currently trying to run a parallelized `RStan` job on a computing cluster in `R`. I am doing this by specifying the following two options:

```
options(mc.cores = parallel::detectCores())
rstan_options(auto_write = TRUE)
```

The above allocates 48 cores available and the total RAM I have is 180 GB. I always thought in theory that more cores and more RAM was better. I am running very long jobs and I am getting insufficient memory errors in my cluster. I am wondering if I am perhaps not giving enough memory to each core. Is it possible that the 48 cores each are splitting the 180 GB and each core is then maxed out?

If I were to use the 180 GB of RAM and instead had 3 cores, would this get around memory errors? Or is it no matter how many cores I have, the total memory will always be used up at some point if its a long job? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RStan is only going to utilize as many cores as there are chains (by default 4). And if you are using a shell on a Linux cluster, it will fork rather than making copies of the data. So, if you have idle cores, you are better off utilizing them to parallelize computations within a Stan program using the `map_rect` function, if possible.

But all of that is probably unrelated to your memory problems. It should not require even 1 GB in most cases.

Comment: Thanks, what do you mean by fork vs. making copies fo the data?

Comment: A fork of a R session essentially keeps the same global workspace (where your data is) and starts multiple threads that can all access that data. This is the mechanism used when running R from a shell. It isn't recommended when running R from a GUI, so in that case, RStan will start several independent processes via sockets, which requires that they each be given a copy of the data. In rare cases with large amounts of data and small amounts of RAM, this could limit the number of cores you can utilize without running out of RAM. But none of that pertains to the use case you described in the OP.